ошибка pytelegrambot и sqlite3 A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful.Error code: 400Description: Bad Request: message text is empty
пишет ошибку, что сообщение пустое, бот принимает переменные,однако бот ничего из них не выдает, одиночный код без бота прекрасно работает, а тут ступор, не могу понят почему.
вот код:


typesearch = " " 
import sqlite3
import telebot
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/users/79165/Desktop/work2/trees.db', check_same_thread=False)


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, threaded=False)

c = db.cursor()






@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])  
# Create Cursor


def start(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, """
        
        напиши привет
        
        """)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, menus);




def menus(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, """
    Сканирование по координатам : /filter_xy
    Сканирование по виду : /filtertype
    Добавить дерево в базу данных : /addtree
    Добавить новый вид деревьев в базу данных : /addtype
    
    
    """);
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message,function_choise)




def function_choise(message):
    print(message.text)
    if message.text == '/filter_xy':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, """напиши в формате самая большая X,самая большая Y,самая маленькая X,самая маленькая Y;без пробелов, 4 числа через запятую""" )

        bot.register_next_step_handler(message,tablesorterxy)





def tablesorterxy(message):
        
        a = message.text.split(',')

        
        bx = int(a[0])
        by = int(a[1])
        sx = int(a[2])
        sy = int(a[3])
        print(bx,by,sx,sy)
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM TREES JOIN TYPES ON TREES.type_id = TYPES.type_id WHERE coord_x > ? AND coord_x < ? AND coord_y > ? AND coord_y < ?" , (sx,bx,sy,by))
        print(c.fetchall() )
        res = ''
        res = c.fetchall()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,res)
        print(bx,by,sx,sy)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message,function_choise)
        #result = c.fetchall() 
        #for row in result: 
        #    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,row)
        print(bx,by,sx,sy)














bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
db.close()




желательно описать причину ошибки и как ее фиксить
очень странная ошибка, поскольку отключение блокировки нескольких потоков не помогло

print(c.fetchall() ) — вы прочитали все строки из результата запроса (если они вообще были). res = c.fetchall() — строки уже закончились в предыдущем вызове fetchall, поэтому здесь в переменную res помещается пустота
